# Remover itens e alterar valor total

Tags: javascript, html, css

Olá, Tenho um problema que estou quebrando a cabeça a tempos e simplesmente não consigo entender por qual motivo isso ocorre... 
Na minha aplicação eu tenho um carrinho que até então insere produtos normalmente, faz a soma dos seus valores e adiciona ao total, porém, quando eu tento remover um item do carrinho ele simplesmente está bagunçando o valor total

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por exemplo, quando removo o Atum que é o primeiro item da lista, ele simplesmente subtrai o valor triplicado, se eu removo o salmão que é o segundo item da lista, ele remove duplicado...

Exemplo removendo o Atum:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O valor fica negativo e no console é como se ele tivesse sido removido 3x com um único click...

Nos elementos ele foi deletado corretamente até

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seguem os códigos que utilizei para criar os elementos, remover e atualizar o valor total do carrinho quando deletado algum item:

Criação dos itens

```html
$(document).ready(function(){
var btnAdcionaCarrinho = $(".btn-adicionar-carrinho");
btnAdcionaCarrinho.click(function(){
    adicionaProduto($(this));
    totalPedido(buscaItensPedido());
});
});
function adicionaProduto(el){ //adiciona produto ao carrinho
    console.log(el);
    var nomeProduto = el.parent().find(".titulo-produto");
    var qtdProduto = el.parent().find(".qtd-produto").val();
    var precoProduto = el.parent().find(".preco-produto").text();
 
    alteraQtdItensCarrinho("add");
    buildItemPedido(nomeProduto.text(),qtdProduto,precoProduto);
    carrinho.find(".btn-remover-item").click(function(){
        console.log($(this));
        alteraQtdItensCarrinho("del");
        removeProduto($(this));
    });
  
}

function buildItemPedido(nomeProduto,qtdProduto,precoProduto){//cria a linha na tabela contendo as informações sobre o pedido
    var novoItem = $("<tr></tr>");
   
    var nomeItem = $("<td></td>").addClass("nome-pedido").text(nomeProduto);
    var qtdItem = $("<td></td>").addClass("qtd-pedido").text(qtdProduto);
    var qtdPrecoItem = $("<td></td>").addClass("qtd-preco-pedido").text(precoProduto);
    var removerItem = $("<td></td>").addClass("remover-item");
    var botaoRemover = $("<span></span>").append("<i></i>").addClass("icon-close btn-remover-item");
    removerItem.append(botaoRemover);
   
    novoItem.append(nomeItem,qtdItem,qtdPrecoItem,removerItem);
    carrinho.append(novoItem);
    
    console.log(novoItem);
    console.log(carrinho);
    return carrinho;
}
```

Remoção do item

```js
function removeProduto(el){// deleta produto do carrinho
    var item = el.parent().parent();
    var itemPreco = item.find(".qtd-preco-pedido").text();
    var itemQtd = item.find(".qtd-pedido").text();
    console.log(item,itemPreco,itemQtd);
    
    subtraiValorTotal(itemPreco,itemQtd);
    
    item.remove();
}
```

Alteração do valor total

```js
function subtraiValorTotal(itemPreco,itemQtd){//diminui o valor total quando um item é removido
   // console.log(itemPreco,itemQtd);
    var precoItem = parseFloat(removeSifrao(itemPreco).replace(",",".")) * parseInt(itemQtd);
    var total = parseFloat(removeSifrao($("#valor-total").text()).replace(",","."));
   // console.log(precoItem.toFixed(2));
   // console.log(total);
    var novoTotal = total - precoItem;
    $("#valor-total").text("R$" + novoTotal.toFixed(2).toString().replace(".",","));
}
```

Comment: Boa pergunta, vou aqui no vizinho checar se ele tem o HTML pra gente poder reproduzir o problema.

Comment: O que tem nessa função `removeSifrao()`?

Comment: Ela remove o R$ do pedido, já que quando adiciono algum item ao carrinho ele acaba indo em forma de string (exemplo: R$ 40,00) e preciso realizar cálculos e para isso ela remove através de uma RegEx o R$ e me retorna o valor convertido já para float

Comment: Quanto ao HTML, ele é basicamente uma tabela sem <tr> alguma, eu as crio na função buildItemPedido quando adiciono um produto ao carrinho

Comment: Tem muitos vícios no código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem alguns problemas no códigos que devem ser corrigidos. Aqui por exemplo:

```
novoTotal.toFixed(2).toString().replace(".",",")
```

Por que `.toString()` se o `.toFixed(2)` já converte o número em string? É redundante fazer isso. Você está convertendo string em string.

Não sei como está a sua função `removeSifrao` mas esta aqui dá conta do recado:

```
function removeSifrao(i){
   i = i.replace("R$","").replace(".","").replace(",",".");
   i = parseFloat(i).toFixed(2);
   return i;
}
```

Veja que você pode tratar o número dentro da função e retornar ele mais limpo do que usar `parseFloat` lá no meio dos códigos.

Compara o código do exemplo funcionando abaixo com o seu e faça as correções:

```js
function removeSifrao(i){
   i = i.replace("R$","").replace(".","").replace(",",".");
   i = parseFloat(i).toFixed(2);
   return i;
}

function removeProduto(el){// deleta produto do carrinho
    var item = $(el).closest("tr");
    var itemPreco = item.find(".qtd-preco-pedido").text();
    var itemQtd = item.find(".qtd-pedido").text();
    subtraiValorTotal(itemPreco,itemQtd);
    item.remove();
}

function subtraiValorTotal(itemPreco,itemQtd){//diminui o valor total quando um item é removido
    var precoItem = (removeSifrao(itemPreco) * itemQtd).toFixed(2);
    var total = removeSifrao($("#valor-total").text());
    var novoTotal = total - precoItem;
    $("#valor-total").text("R$" + novoTotal.toFixed(2).replace(".",","));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>prod 1</td>
      <td class="qtd-pedido">5</td>
      <td class="qtd-preco-pedido">R$5,80</td>
      <td><button onclick="removeProduto(this)">X</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>prod 2</td>
      <td class="qtd-pedido">3</td>
      <td class="qtd-preco-pedido">R$10,90</td>
      <td><button onclick="removeProduto(this)">X</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>prod 3</td>
      <td class="qtd-pedido">3</td>
      <td class="qtd-preco-pedido">R$5,90</td>
      <td><button onclick="removeProduto(this)">X</button></td>
   </tr>
</table>
Total: <div id="valor-total">R$79,40</div>
```

Outra coisa, para fazer multiplicações e divisões de números, não precisa converter o tipo (usar `parseInt` ou `parseFloat`). Só seria necessário em caso de soma ou subtração.

Comment: Agora tudo funciona corretamente x.x 
Eu ainda to iniciando com JS e ainda tenho muito o que aprender xD Mal sabia que o replace já converte para String... Obrigado por compartilhar um conhecimento extra =D

Comment: O replace não, o toFixed que converte pra string :)

Comment: ops, exato kkkkk

Comment: Obgradíssimo!...